# Testing "framework" for scripts with nonstandard filenames

Tags: bash, shell

Here are many comments on some questions (especially for shell) that say basically one or more of the following:

- *This will fail on file names that contain spaces, newlines*, etc,
- *This will fail if the file is a symbolic link (or not)*,
- *This will fail if the `$filaneme` is a directory and not regular file*,
- and so on.

While I understand that every script needs its own testing environment, but
these are some *common things* for what the script should be *immune* against.

So, my intention is to write a script what will create some directory hierarchy
with "specially crafted" file names for testing purposes.

The question is: *what "special" file names are good for this test?*

Currently I have (the script creates files and directories) with:

- space in the file name
- newline in the file name
- file name that starts with one of:

  - `-` (like command argument)
  - `#` (comment char)
  - `!` (command history)
- file name that contains one of:

  - `|` char (pipe)
  - `()` chars
  - `*` and `?` (wildcards)
- file name with unicode characters
- all above for the directories
- symbolic link to the directory
- symbolic link to the file

Any other idea what I shouldn't miss?

Comment: I'd be interested in writings scripts that pass all these files. Would you care to share your resulting script once you have it written? Perhaps then others would want to improve it or add other cases later on. I suggest creating a repository for the script on http://github.com

Comment: it's ok, github is very simple if you give it a try. There are nice helps too. Just sign up and it will guide you.

Answer (score 3):

What comes to my mind:

- quotes in the filename single and double
- the `$` character at the start
- several redirection characters like `>` `<` `<<` `<<<`
- the `~` char ($HOME)
- the ';' (as command delimiter)
- backslash in the filename `\`

basically, go thru ascii table and test all chars, if you think that you need this :)

Some another comments:

- If you want test scripts for the stack-overflow questions, you should create one file with the OP's content (calling as the "basic file")
- And the all above "special files" should be symlinks to the above basic file. With this method you can easily modify the content of the files (you need change only one - the basic).
- Or, if symlinks not a solution for you use `hard-links`.

Not directly about special characters in the filenames, but it is good care about:

- different case filenames, especially for images like `image.jpg` `image.JPG`, same filename only different extension

**EDIT**: Ideas from the comments:

- Very long filenames, lots and lots of files, and very deep directory hierarchies (*tripleee*)

Comment: Can you please pay more attention to grammar and rewrite your first two "other comments"? They are quite hard to understand.

Comment: Unfortunately, my grammar is only as good as good is google-translate.  So, if it is really bad - please, mark it for deletion. Sorry for caused problems. ;(

Comment: No, you raise good points and the answer is definitely useful. I was just hoping you could improve it.

Comment: Very long filenames, lots and lots of files, and very deep directory hierarchies also trip up sime systems.